# How to build a non minified production code with webapp generator gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, yeoman

I have scaffolded a project with webapp generator. The project only works with localhost but not if I open file directly in browser with file scheme. The url `http://localhost:9000/` opens the index.html file in `app` folder but `http://localhost:9000/styles/main.css` opens `app../.tmp/styles/main.css`. It is quite weired how localhost comes one directory back without actually the path opened in window bar. The problem this has caused is that `index.html` uses `bower_componnets/example.css` folder with localhost only. With file scheme there doesn't exist bower_components folder inside app. So I cannot use `app` folder without localhost.

The practical problem at hand is that I have to upload a working demo of static webpage on a server which will be used by back end developer to make dynamic code. Now I cannot upload app folder because it works only on local host. With `gulp build` I get a `dist` folder which works with file scheme but it is all minified and doesn't use cdn. The backend developer cannot use minified html.

I have wasted two days fighting with gulp bower yeoman and webapp. I thought this would reduce my time by automating tasks and I will focus entierly on code. But what it has done is I have lost focus entirely from actual work and I am focusing on fixing xyz issue after every hour with bower, npm, gulp. Instead had I spent 5 minutes to download or find cdn of plugins and included them manually in my code I would have saved 2 days. So gulp bower make 5 mins work into 2 days work. What a brilliant tool. Well.. The question is:

1. How to build a non minified production code similar to dist folder with webapp generator gulp?

---

**Edit My temporary solution:**

As we needed unminified html css and js files for our project I added a new task in gulp file to generate a `demo` folder similar to `dist`. I simply copied dist task and change `gulp.src('dist/**/*')` to `gulp.src('demo/**/*')`. For this task to generate files in styles and js folders I added `.pipe(gulp.dest('demo'))` at places where `.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});` existed. I also took care to put `.pipe(gulp.dest('demo'));
});` before gulp uses minify tasks. Here is the relevant gulp.js code:

```
// some code here

gulp.task('html', ['styles', 'scripts'], () => {
  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe($.useref({searchPath: ['.tmp', 'app', '.']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('demo')) // I added my code here
    .pipe($.if(/\.js$/, $.uglify({compress: {drop_console: true}})))
    .pipe($.if(/\.css$/, $.cssnano({safe: true, autoprefixer: false})))
    .pipe($.if(/\.html$/, $.htmlmin({      
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      minifyCSS: true,
      minifyJS: {compress: {drop_console: true}},
      processConditionalComments: true,
      removeComments: true,
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
      removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true      
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('images', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.cache($.imagemin()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('demo/images')) // I added this
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});

gulp.task('fonts', () => {
  return gulp.src(require('main-bower-files')('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}', function (err) {})
    .concat('app/fonts/**/*'))
    .pipe($.if(dev, gulp.dest('.tmp/fonts'), gulp.dest('dist/fonts'), gulp.dest('demo/fonts') )  ); // I added demo here too
});

gulp.task('extras', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'app/*',
    '!app/*.html'
  ], {
    dot: true
  }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist')).pipe(gulp.dest('demo')); // I added this
});

gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['.tmp', 'dist', 'demo'])); // I added demo here

//some code here 


/*New Custom tasks*/

gulp.task('demo-build', ['lint', 'html', 'images', 'fonts', 'extras'], () => {
  return gulp.src('demo/**/*');
});
```

Unfortunately I couln't find a few to stop gulp concatenating all css files and js files into one `vendor.js/css` file. Also I couldn't find way to replace local plugins with their cdn's.

One thing I have learned very well. npm, gulp etc are not for front end developers; they are for **nodeJs** developers. A task that can be done in 5 minutes takes 5 hours with these. But obviously nodejs dev could take benefit from this because he could customize these plugins as per his need.

Comment: What is the version of your `generator-webapp`?

Comment: @Nhan It should be the latest one but I am not sure. I installed it 2 days ago with latest npm. `yo --v` and `generator-webapp --v` both are giving some weird results`.

Comment: Okay I got it, see my answer below.

Comment: Your requirements are not difficult to get, I think it's easier to achieve by writing gulp tasks from scratch instead of modifying this file, it has been included with so many functionalities.

Comment: @Nhan Yes, it would be better for me to make my own webapp generator. But this requires me to first learn these tools. Till I learn them it would be better to not use them at all.

Answer (score 1):

Open `gulpfile.js` and find the `html` task. You should see this block:

```
.pipe($.if('/\.html$/', $.htmlmin({

  // ...
  // many options
  // ...

})))
```

Comment the block then run Gulp again, you will see your `index.html` unminified.

Comment: This stops html minification but not css and js minification. Also I needed to stop concatenation of js and css files so I could replace them with their cdn's. Thanks for your help. I think my knowledge is not yet at the level of these tools. It's better for me to do things manually.

Comment: Just after these lines, you have to comment the two following lines ".pipe($.if(/\.js$/, $.uglify({compress: {drop_console: true}}))) .pipe($.if(/\.css$/, $.postcss([cssnano({safe: true, autoprefixer: false})])))

Answer (score 0):

You have to comment these lines too :

```
.pipe($.if(/\.js$/, $.uglify({compress: {drop_console: true}})))
.pipe($.if(/\.css$/, $.postcss([cssnano({safe: true, autoprefixer: false})])))
```